# Object generic return value (wrapper class) won't allow for primitive variable assignment

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have the following getElement object from my node class:

```
  public T getElement () {
        return element;
    }
```

In a generic T class I have the following more specialized getElement object to access a linked list that's front is stored in an array:

```
public T getElement(int col, int row)
```

Then in another class I have the following variable assignment that uses these objects:

int x = intGrid.getElement(0, 0).getElement();

The above line gives the following error:

```
The method getElement() is undefined for the type Integer
```

I can't really show more of the codes details since I'm working with someone else on their code project. Any ideas on how I can alter public T getElement(int col, int row) to fix this? I cannot change the node classes getElement nor can I alter that variable declaration.

Comment: If `getElement(0, 0)` returns an Integer, why would you expect that Integer to have a getElement method?  Wouldn’t you need your grid to contain `Node<Integer>` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `intGrid.getElement(0,0)` is returning an `Integer` Java object.

The class `Integer` does not extends `YourNodeClass` with the `getElement` method.

I can't speak more about without seeing your code, but I would recommend to avoid inheritance.